# Panel that slide from top to bottom Android

Tags: android

I want to implement sliding panel that slide on touch from top to bottom in Android like this design

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also implement same via `Translate Animation`.
First you need to write xml file under res/anim folder.

```
slide_down_service.xml 
<translate 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
      android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
      android:toXDelta="0%p"
      android:fromYDelta="0%"
      android:toYDelta="120%">
</translate>
```

you can change YDelta value as per requirement.
Then you need to intialize Animations in following way in your activity.

```
  Animation animContentDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down_service);
            animContentDown.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
```

And then start your animation : `yourview.startAnimation(animContentDown);`

Answer (score 0):

That's a [sliding drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html). Implementation is easy, you just need the two views for the handle and the content. Be careful though, it has been deprecated.

Comment: does it support sliding from top to bottom?

Comment: @MSaudi this supports that https://github.com/drxeno02/androidprojects-book2-slidingdrawer